# Securing Web API for mobile devices

Tags: security, api, oauth

We have an API for our local search website, which is used on our Mobile Apps.

Currently,

- The API is not public
- No user data is provided in the API
- is running over http

I want to secure our data which is sent over the API. I have done some research, and looks like Oauth is the way to go

- Is Oauth the right way to do it? (we'll currently use 2 legged oauth but in future if we need user permission we'll move to 3 legged oauth)
- Do we need https for the API? Would a self signed certificate work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth's best suited for scenarios that involve a third party (Provider). For example: sign in with Facebook.

If the user has to login to your service to access the API, you can use basic authentication. (Attach credentials to Http header over Https)

Finally: Yes you need Https. And a self-signed certificate can work if you control the client and the server. For example for Android you can import your certificates):

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html (Self-signed server certificate section)

However, if you are creating a web client, user would get a warning for untrusted site.